# How to call a PHP function with Ajax when the user clicks a button

Tags: ajax, wpdb

I'm developing a wordpress site using custom templates/themes, but I'm having trouble. I want to use Ajax to call a function when a user clicks a button. On one page, I have a button like so:

```
<p class='form-submit'>
        <input name='message_read' type='submit' class='submit button mark-as-read' value= 'Mark as read' />
    </p>
```

And I have a jQuery/Ajax function like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
   jQuery(".mark-as-read").click(function () {
    console.log('The function is hooked up');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'mark_message_as_read',
        },
        success: function (output) {
           console.log(output);
        }
        });
    });
});
```

The function above lives in `wp-content/themes/my-theme/js/wp_ajax_calls.js`. I added the script to the site like so:

1) I added this to my functions.php file:

```
wp_enqueue_script(  'ajax calls', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/wp_ajax_calls.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
```

2) I included the script in the header.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mysite//wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/wp_ajax_calls.js"></script>
```

When I click the button as is, the console.log statement shows up. To my understanding, I want my ajax function to call a php function that will let me use $wpdb. I have this in functions.php:

```
function mark_message_as_read() {
    global $wpdb;
    // do stuff. 
}
```

This is where I am getting confused. I have two main questions:

**1) I think I am supposed to have some add_action() 's somewhere, but I don't know where to put them and I also don't know what hook I should use.**

**2) Additionally, I want to be able to pass data (the message id) to the php function for my db query. How do I pass an argument to that function?**

I don't want to use something like `if( isset($_POST['message_whatever']) ) twentyfifteen_message_whatever();` because of the way I have messages set up.

Happy to provide more information if needed. Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Please see [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/enqueuing/#ajax-action).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Create a child theme so you don't mess with the code of an existing theme because next time you'll update the theme, you may loose all your changes (see [Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes))
2. Here is how to pass values to your ajax request:

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
      jQuery(".mark-as-read").click(function () {
       console.log('The function is hooked up');
       jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
           data: {
               action: 'mark_message_as_read',
               // add your parameters here
               message_id: $('.your-selector').val()
           },
           success: function (output) {
              console.log(output);
           }
           });
       });
   });
   ```

You may do some research on Nonces too, to add a layer of security to your app: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces

3. Finally, the PHP code to handle the request (here too you should handle the nonce in real life code):

   ```
   // register the ajax action for authenticated users
   add_action('wp_ajax_mark_message_as_read', 'mark_message_as_read');

   // register the ajax action for unauthenticated users
   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mark_message_as_read', 'mark_message_as_read');

   // handle the ajax request
   function mark_message_as_read() {
       $message_id = $_REQUEST['message_id'];

       // add your logic here...

       // in the end, returns success json data
       wp_send_json_success([/* some data here */]);

       // or, on error, return error json data
       wp_send_json_error([/* some data here */]);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll definitely take a look at nonces as well. :D